# Cannot get css to move my little text box into center

Tags: css, html, margin, opacity

I am trying to get a little box into the center of my screen, I had just text centered fine and just floated my aside, but I added a little box to make my text more visible using opacity. Now the text and the translucent box it sits on is over my aside and float won't work and margins leave like a weird box where the text would be without the margin's. Am I doing something wrong here or how do I fix it? PS i am using a 'technique' i guess from w3schools website it is in my comment later.

HTML:

```
<div class="myLinks">
        <aside class="myLinks">
            <nav class="myLinks">
                <a href=""> content </a> <br/> <br/>
                <a href=""> content </a> <br/> <br/>
                <a href=""> content </a> <br/> <br/>
                <a href=""> content </a> <br/> <br/>
                <a href=""> content </a> <br/> <br/>
                <a href=""> content </a> <br/> <br/>
            </nav>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="homePageContent">
        <div class="transparency"> <!-- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp -->
        <h2> <em> Hello, </em> </h2>
         <em> <p> co <br/>

        n <br/>

        t<br/>

        e <br/>

        n <br/>

        t <br/>

        content <br/>

        content <br/>

        content <br/>

        content <br/>

        content<br/>

        content <br/>

        content</p> </em> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
     .myLinks{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #0c64e8, #989898); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #0c64e8, #989898); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #0c64e8, #989898); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0c64e8, #989898); /* Standard syntax */
    padding-left: 5px;
    width:120px;
    border-color: #323232; 
    border-style: double;
    float:left;
}
.homePageContent{
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    width:400px;
    height:530px;
    border:1px solid gray;  
}
.transparency{
    width: 400px;
    height: 530px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

Comment: I also tried floating and everything but the footer moved way up for some reason.

Comment: Don't use break tags for layout or spacing...it's **just wrong**.

Comment: Also the `center` element has been removed from the HTML spec and should no longer be used.

Comment: Ok...now add an extra bit of space with **half** a break tag...that's why it's wrong and unprofessional.

Comment: honestly i dont know what that is and i learned html and css in like an hour so i wasnt to thorough but I'll look into it

Comment: [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/) and [**http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/**](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the box in the center of your screen you can use margin:0 auto
Try this:

```
.homePageContent{
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    width:400px;
    height:530px;
    border:1px solid gray;  
    margin:0 auto
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3vd7/

Answer (score 0):

You have your aside floated and the main content not floated.  Mixing floated and non-floated elements like that will cause what you are seeing.  Change your CSS to this should get you going in the right direction:

```
.homePageContent{
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    width:400px;
    height:530px;
    border:1px solid gray;  
    float: left;
}
```